# Have Select Dropdown of Taxonomy but allow user to enter new term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

Is there a way to have my Taxonomy Terms in Dropdown but also allow the user to enter a new term (Like autocomplete widget does) if they don't see their term in the select list?

So essentially I would have a backup to allow the user to create one.

My use-case is I have a bunch of businesses, when someone adds a new one, if they don't see their business type, they can just add a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Install the Select or Other module**

You can use the [Select or Other](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module to add a dropdown with an *Other* option.

Selecting *Other* prompts the user to enter the new value in a separate field.

Your question asked to add the new business type directly; this module adds it to a separate field (however, an admin can later add the business type as a taxonomy term if you wish).

**Advantages of this approach**

- You get admin approval of user input.  This way a bad user can't enter something like *Sex sex sex* which then appears as a business type on your site.
- You have control over how long the list gets instead of letting users add an unlimited number of terms.

**Coding it yourself**

You can also code this yourself pretty easily using the States API instead of installing the Select or Other module.

Add a new text field, `field_businesstype_other`, to store the *Other* values for `field_businesstype`.

Create a taxonomy term named *Other* in your "business type" vocabulary.

Then, in `hook_form_alter()`, add something like this:

```
  $form['field_businesstype_other']['#states'] = array(
    'visible' => array(
      'select[name="field_businesstype"]' => array(
        array('value' => '123'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Replace `123` with the term ID of the *Other* term you created.